# Active Directory smartcard authorization

Tags: c#, security, authentication, active-directory, smartcard

Im looking how to perform smart card authentication against AD from C# client application. I need to make logon into application using the smart card. Could somebody give me clue where to find API for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can call logonuser with serialized credential:

- the hash of the certificate will become the username
- the PIN of the smart card will become the password

But to get the certificate, you will have to enumerate the cryptoapi containter then access the certificate using CryptGetKeyParam(KP_CERTIFICATE)